# How select referenced entity in nhibernate queryover

Tags: nhibernate, select, lazy-loading, eager-loading, queryover

I Have a entity with a property referencing other entity (ReferenceEntity in examples).

With HQL i can do this:

```
select e.ReferenceEntity from Entity e where e.Id = :entityId
```

NHibernate will give me the ReferenceEntity instance without lazy.

With query over im trying do this:

```
Session.QueryOver<Entity>()
.Where(e => e.Id == entityId)
.Select(e => e.ReferenceEntity)
.SingleOrDefault<ReferenceEntity>()
```

With QueryOver Nhibernate is giving me the ReferenceEntity but lazy.

I wanna get ReferenceEntity with eager loading using queryover like i do with hql.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Suggestion #1

You could do a little bit of LINQ manipulation after you execute the query to grab the data you want.

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(e => e.Id == entityId)        // Filter,
    .Fetch(e => e.ReferenceEntity).Eager // join the desired data into the query,
    .List()                              // execute database query,
    .Select(e => e.ReferenceEntity)      // then grab the desired data in-memory with LINQ.
    .SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine("Name = " + result.Name);
```

It's simple and gets the job done.

In my test, it resulted in a single query.  Here's the output:

```
SELECT
    this_.Id as Id0_1_, this_.Name as Name0_1_, this_.ReferenceEntity_id as Referenc3_0_1_,
    q5379349_r2_.Id as Id1_0_, q5379349_r2_.Name as Name1_0_
FROM
    [Entity] this_
    left outer join [ReferenceEntity] q5379349_r2_
        on this_.ReferenceEntity_id=q5379349_r2_.Id
WHERE this_.Id = @p0;
```

### Suggestion #2

Another approach would be to use an EXISTS subquery, which would be slightly more complex, but would return the right result the first time without any need for post-database manipulation:

```
ReferenceEntity alias = null;
var result = Session.QueryOver(() => alias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereExists(QueryOver.Of<Entity>()
        .Where(e => e.Id == entityId)                 // Filtered,
        .Where(e => e.ReferenceEntity.Id == alias.Id) // correlated,
        .Select(e => e.Id))                           // and projected (EXISTS requires a projection).
    .SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine("Name = " + result.Name);
```

Tested - results in single query:

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id1_0_, this_.Name as Name1_0_
FROM [ReferenceEntity] this_
WHERE exists (
    SELECT this_0_.Id as y0_
    FROM [Entity] this_0_
    WHERE this_0_.Id = @p0 and this_0_.ReferenceEntity_id = this_.Id);
```

Comment: Your first suggestion leads to [n+1 selects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem) and possible performance issues. The second one may yield only one DB query, but inside this you will have `WHERE EXISTS ( ... )`, which may cause the same undesired complexity (depending on the RDBMS).

Comment: I am hoping for a `QueryOver` expression resulting in a simple `SELECT` projecting all the fields from the already joined `ReferenceEntity` table.

Comment: Edited to include actual queries executed by NHibernate.  Both approaches result in just a single query being executed.  Can you post your test that resulted in a Select N+1?

Comment: What database server are you targeting?  SQL Server produces *almost* identical query plans for the two queries - it shows the EXISTS query actually using an INNER join under the covers, so it might actually be faster than the other query in some situations.

Comment: You're obviously right. I didn't read your first query well enough, and missed the `Fetch().Eager` clause. Sorry about that. Thanks a lot for documenting the queries with generated SQL and for the Sql Server insights. Here's 110 rep - don't spend it all at once ;)

Comment: Hi Daniel! Your second query does exactly what I want. In my opnion it should be more simple like the example I did in my question, but your second query works very well. Thank you and sorry for my delay.

Comment: I'm new to NHib and it feels weird that what looks like a simple use case is so convoluted. Looks like I'm missing something.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I want to point out an issue with the second solution. Caching will store the result of the query in the query space for `ReferenceEntity` even though it is ideally placed in the query space for `Entity`. The first solution doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You correctly, this is what You need:

```
Session.QueryOver<Entity>()
 .Where(e => e.Id == entityId)
 //!!!
 .Fetch(e=>e.ReferenceEntity).Eager
 .Select(e => e.ReferenceEntity)
 .SingleOrDefault<ReferenceEntity>()
```

Comment: Hi. I did how you say, but it's not working. QueryOver is returning to me Castle.Proxies.GroupProxy. NHibernate is executing this query: SELECT this_.group_id as y0_ FROM publishes this_ WHERE this_.content_id = :p0;:p0 = 72. I wanna Group eager. With Hql i can get Entity eager. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Session.QueryOver<Entity>()
 .Where(e => e.Id == entityId)
 .Fetch(e=>e.ReferenceEntity).Eager
 .Select(e => e.ReferenceEntity)
 .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ReferenceEntity>())
 .SingleOrDefault<ReferenceEntity>()
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The generated SQL only projects the identifier of the referenced entity: `SELECT this_.ReferenceEntityId as y0_ FROM Entity this_ WHERE this_.Id = 'a67b894e-bc53-e011-bd88-22a08ed629e5'`